# Prove the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for integrals

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Show that for any $f,\,g: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where $f^2$ and $g^2$ are integrable on some interval $I\subset \mathbb{R}$,

$$\left(\int_{I} f(x)g(x)\, dx\right)^2 \leq \int_{I} f^2(x)\, dx \int_{I} g^2(x)\, dx$$

I know that for any $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $(\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{y})^2 \leq (\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x})(\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{y})$, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in the L2 norm, and I have figured out its proof. But I can't figure out how to prove the case where we are integrating over $x$.

Comment: I think it is easiest to use the abstract proof that $$|\langle x, y\rangle| \le \sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle \langle y,y\rangle}$$ for all inner product spaces with inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rearrange $\int_I(f-\lambda g)^2dx\ge0$ for $\lambda=\frac{\int_Ifgdx}{\int_Ig^2dx}$.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Once I isolated the discriminant of $\lambda = 0$ on the left-hand side, it was a simple matter to show that the discriminant had to be nonpositive.

Comment: @J.G. Can't we have $\int_I g^2 = 0$? Actually I'm trying to prove this inequality for $f,g:Q\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ where $Q$ is a rectangle. But once we're not asking for $g$ to be strictly positive or continuous.

Comment: The last comment is incomplete: once we're not asking $g$ to be strictly positive or continuous, we can have $g\ne 0$ with $\int_Ig = 0$